# How do I pause a JavaFX MediaPlayer when it reaches the end?

Tags: java, javafx

When playing a video using `MediaPlayer` and `MediaView` in JavaFX, when the player reaches the end of the video, the status of the player remains in `PLAYING` and this is documented on [`MediaPlayer.Status`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html):

> Reaching the end of the media (or the stopTime if this is defined) while playing does not cause the status to change from PLAYING. Therefore, for example, if the media is played to its end and then a manual seek to an earlier time within the media is performed, playing will continue from the new media time.

I tried making it pause when reaching the end by doing this:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
});
```

but it remains in `PLAYING` mode. This version with debugging information:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
    System.out.println("end of media");
    System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getStatus());
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getStatus()));
});
```

show the effect as the output on the console is:

```
end of media
PLAYING
PLAYING
```

Any ideas why is that or how to force the media player to go into `PAUSE` state?

I debugged both situations: plain-old-pause and pause at the end of the video and they behave identically up to the call of [`GSTMediaPlayer.gstPause(long refNativeMedia)`](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/master/modules/media/src/main/java/com/sun/media/jfxmediaimpl/platform/gstreamer/GSTMediaPlayer.java#L282) which is a native method, so, I hit a wall.

Comment: I don’t think the change in status happens right away.  Try placing your last println statement in a Platform.runLater.  Or, listen to changes in the MediaPlayer’s status property.

Comment: I'm also wondering about the same issue. My question to you is: "How can some media be paused when is FINISHED"? I can see what you want to achieve - to pause the media on the LAST frame. But - there is no last frame, the media is consumed (including the last frame). Where is the logic in your aproach?

Comment: @VGR: done. Same output. I wasn't basing my conclusion on that output, but on the fact that after reaching the end, I seek to another point and it immediately starts playing (because it's in playing mode, not paused).

Comment: @zlakad: there's no FINISHED state in the state machine. I just don't want it to start playing automatically when you seek, it's very unfriendly.

Comment: Uh. I see. My comment was in 'question' mode. I'll keep an eye on this... good luck

Comment: I gather you can’t use the stop() method because you want to be able to seek?  (The docs say “While stopped, the player will not respond to playback position changes requested by seek(javafx.util.Duration).”)

Comment: @VGR: I actually didn't even think about that. Not being able to seek breaks my UI, but let me see if I can workaround something from there.

Comment: @VGR: stopping and then pausing might be a workaround for now.